# Stopping orgmode #+INCLUDE command showing up in PDF export

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I have an orgmode file that I'm exporting to PDF via LaTeX.  It imports another file containing tikz code to create a diagram using the #+INCLUDE "./tikz-code.org" command.  This works fine and the diagram is included in the PDF with no problems.  However the #+INCLUDE "./tikz-code.org" command is also included in the PDF file.  Is there a way for me to stop this happening?

Many thanks,

David

Many thanks @Nick.  I'm using version 8.2.10 (which comes with Ubuntu 17.04).  I'm using the apa6 LaTeX class and my code is:

```
#+INCLUDE "./flow-chart.org"
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 12cm
#+CAPTION: Chart Caption
#+LABEL: fig:flow-chart 
#+RESULTS:
[[file:flow-chart.pdf]]
```

Comment: Details matter: can you provide a minimal example that mimics your file and exhibits the problem? In particular, what does the #+INCLUDE line look like (plus  a few lines around it)? And what version of org-mode are you using?

Comment: FWIW, I tried a simple experiment and I *don't* get the #+INCLUDE line included in the output.  Org mode version 9.0.9 (release_9.0.9-573-g09e612)

Comment: OK, looking at the code I've posted has made me realise my error.  I've omitted the colon from `#+INCLUDE`.  I'm an idiot.  Apologies for wasting your time @Nick and thanks again for trying to help me out.

Comment: Glad you found it! I usually spot missing colons, but I missed it completely this time.